# Replace softkeys with another layout or view in an android application

Tags: android, layout, android-softkeyboard, emoji, emoticons

I want to implement emoticons in my app. The emoticon view/layout should appear in place of the soft keyboard (as in WhatsApp). i.e. When user clicks on an edittext the keyboard should appear (which is normal default behaviour) but when the user clicks on another button, a layout with emoticons should appear in the same place where the soft keyboard was. Please help!

Comment: Full example of emoji keyboard: https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: That doesn't help. I know how to show the emoticons. My question is related to the layout as how can I place it at the same position as a soft keyboard.